# Get max y at intersection of line and figure

Tags: calculus, geometry

The blue line is created by the expression cos(arcsin(n)) where n is the range 0 to 1 (here using a step of 0.3).
Now two green lines, both with the length 1, connect at the blue line creating a triangle that 'expands' and 'collapses' creating the full figure.

The question is how do I calculate max(y) for where the black vertical line (x=0.9) intersects the green figure? Or how do I get an expression for the upper edge of the total figure that the green lines span.

Reading from the figure I make it out to be ~0.5304

[image: figure 1]